# Redirect Url to my app after auth 2.0 in Uber api

Tags: android, web-services, redirect, uber-api

Im integrating uber api with my android application. In the case of auth 2.0 what should i give the return url to redirect after successful authorization from uber to enter in to my app.  here is my uber LoginActivity

```
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    settings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(UberLoginActivity.this, "Please wait", "Loading...");
    webView.loadUrl("https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize?client_id=MDyPSkkFFSZHKcntIg9j2mhM7XP665R1&response_type=code");

    SessionConfiguration config = new SessionConfiguration.Builder()
            .setClientId("***********") //This is necessary
            .setRedirectUri("what should be added ") //This is necessary if you'll be using implicit grant
            .setServerToken("*********************")
            .setEnvironment(SessionConfiguration.Environment.SANDBOX) //Useful for testing your app in the sandbox environment
            .setScopes(Arrays.asList(Scope.PROFILE, Scope.RIDE_WIDGETS)) //Your scopes for authentication here
            .build();

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            if (progressBar.isShowing())
            {
                progressBar.dismiss();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                                    String description, String failingUrl)
        {
            view.loadUrl("about:blank");
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), " Please check network connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use SSO for handling on android. Check out the relevant code in the android widget tutorial: https://developer.uber.com/docs/ride-requests/tutorials/widget/android#login

This will use the uber app to authenticate the user, otherwise will redirect to app store. Please follow up if you still prefer to use a webview.

Comment: But im getting the error - invalid auth 2.0 credentials.. !

Comment: Im not using uber widget . Im using uber client library integration. I need the format for redirect uri

Comment: Using the client library you can implement sso login which is a better experience for your users. Otherwise, see the correct way to format your oauth requests: https://developer.uber.com/docs/ride-requests/guides/authentication/introduction#oauth-20.